# Control the position of the vertical scrollbars

Tags: c#, forms

I have a multi-line textbox (let's call it textBox1) that has plenty of text inside.

After doing a search, I highlight the string I was looking for with:

```
textBox1.SelectionStart = textBox1.Text.ToLower().IndexOf(STRING);  
textBox1.SelectionLength = STRING.Length;
```

Now when I call the form that contains the textbox it highlights the selected text, but what I would like to do is that the scrollbars would scroll automatically to the highlighted text.

I tried

```
textBox1.ScrollToCaret();
```

But didn't work.

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: FYI, there is no need to mark your subject lines with tags (like "[c#]"), we have tags for that.

Comment: oh, sorry. Thanks for the heads up. It's a habit I've had for a very long time. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What event are you firing this from? The `Form` probably isn't in a state where it can process this. If you call from [`Form.Load`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.load.aspx) it will be too soon. If you call from [`Form.Shown`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.shown.aspx), it should work properly.

```
private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    var STRING = "Suspendisse mi risus";

    textBox1.SelectionStart = textBox1.Text.IndexOf(STRING);
    textBox1.SelectionLength = STRING.Length;

    textBox1.ScrollToCaret();
}
```

Comment: So that was the problem.

Thanks for clearing that up. So simple.

It didn't even ocurred to me.

Thank you again.